# Geometric Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question that involves a certain criteria of a random variable as shown:
[image]

The random variable $X$ has the distribution $Geo(0.2)$ and I would love it if someone could explain what the question actually wants. I am at a loss when this type of question crops up.

*EDIT*
I have managed to get what the answer wants bar the last section which requires me to multiply my answer by two, anyone know why? My answer was $0.032$ but the worked answer multiplies that by two...

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different but commonly used parametrizations of a geometric random variable.  One version states that $$\Pr[X = x] = (1-p)^{x-1} p, \quad x = 1, 2, 3, \ldots.$$  The other has $$\Pr[X = x] = (1-p)^x p, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots.$$  Note that they are computationally the same, but the second one allows $X = 0$ whereas the first does not.  You need to be clear on which one you intend to use for this question.

The interpretation of the first version can be thought of as the total number of independent Bernoulli trials (each with probability of success $p$) needed to observe the first success.  For example, if you have a coin whose probability of landing heads is $p$, the first parametrization gives you the probability that the first head you see occurs on the $x^{\rm th}$ toss.

The interpretation of the second version is the total number of **failures before** observing the first success.  In the same example, this gives the probability that you see $x$ tails up to the first observation of heads.

For the sake of argument, suppose we are going with the second definition, so that $X = 0$ is a possible outcome.  Then we are told that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent geometric random variables with parameter $p = 0.2$, and we want the probability that $\Pr[X_1 + X_2 = 3]$.  To get this, we note that the only way $X_1 + X_2 = 3$ is if exactly one of the following mutually exclusive events occurs:  $$ (X_1, X_2) \in \{(0,3), (1,2), (2,1), (3,0)\}.$$  And since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, we have $$\Pr[X_1 = x_1 \cap X_2 = x_2] = \Pr[X_1 = x_1] \Pr[X_2 = x_2].$$  So it follows that $$\Pr[X_1 + X_2 = 3] = \sum_{k=0}^3 \Pr[X_1 = k]\Pr[X_2 = 3-k] = \sum_{k=0}^3 (1-p)^k p \cdot (1-p)^{3-k} p = \ldots.$$